# How to get values AND indices of duplicate items in a list?

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I have a list of file names (targetFileList), some of which are duplicates (ex. I have two files called m4.txt). The following statement finds the duplicated filenames and adds them to another list (currentTargetFiles):

`currentTargetFiles = targetFileList.FindAll(item => item == baselineFilename);`

As is, this line is returning a list of strings (filenames), which is good, but I also need their index value. Is there some way to modify it so that it also returns the indices of the files?

Comment: FWIW: There is likely a better way than finding the index and the "real problem" can likely be solved - perhaps "more efficiently" - without such an operation. I very seldom index into an IList.

Comment: @pst oh I'm sure there is but right now I've got other lists this one needs to sync to and I'm doing that by using the index.

Comment: yes I need the indices of all the duplicated items

Comment: sorry, I thought that part was pretty clear when I said "indices of the files" rather than "index of the last/first file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all the items, with their indexes, with:

```
tempList = targetFileList.Select((item, index) => 
    new { Value = item, Index = index }).Where(x => x.Value == baselineFilename);
```

Now, you can create lists of the names and corresponding indexes with:

```
var indexes = tempList.Select(x => x.Index).ToList();
```

And the values:

```
currentTargetFiles = tempList.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Then, `indexes[0]` will hold the list index of `currentTargetFiles[0]`.

Comment: that where clause was causing an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @user1985189 Like with the other answer, you'll have to do something with the pairs of values/indices. If just the indices are desired at this point, appending `.Select(x => x.Index).ToList()` will result in `List<int>` (which still isn't `List<string>`, but it should show the idea).

Comment: @pst thanks I appreciate the effort you've made but this linq stuff is way over my head. I think I'm going to go back to the drawing board and see if there's another work around. I'll give you a bunch of upvotes though for the effort!

Comment: @user1985189 LINQ is *totally worth learning*. It takes awhile (many developers do not have a "functional language background"), sure, but once the basic constructs are worked out it can be used to greatly simplify numerous common tasks. Grouping, filtering, intersections/joins, transformations, etc .. it is a tool that is to be expected in the toolbox of a competent C# developer. (Just because there is a tool, doesn't mean it should be used; but it should be available because there are cases in which it is the *correct* tool.)

Comment: @pst I'm sure it is very valuable. If I ever end up in a job involving C# programming I'll be sure to read up on it. (Right now I'm in a 4 month coop term and this is my first exposure to C# - previously have only done Java in school and we were never introduced to linq)

Comment: @user1985189: See my updated answer. I'll chime in with pst and say *learn LINQ*. It's something that employers expect C# programmers to know and be able to use.

Answer (score 7):

Well, here is my answer to "find the duplicate names and their indices". It might not fit the presented problem exactly, as there is no `baselineFilename` considered - but that is covered by other answers. YMMV.

```
var names = new [] {"a", "a", "c", "b", "a", "b"};

var duplicatesWithIndices = names
    // Associate each name/value with an index
    .Select((Name, Index) => new { Name, Index })
    // Group according to name
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    // Only care about Name -> {Index1, Index2, ..}
    .Select(xg => new {
        Name = xg.Key,
        Indices = xg.Select(x => x.Index)
    })
    // And groups with more than one index represent a duplicate key
    .Where(x => x.Indices.Count() > 1);

// Now, duplicatesWithIndices is typed like:
//   IEnumerable<{Name:string,Indices:IEnumerable<int>}>

// Let's say we print out the duplicates (the ToArray is for .NET 3.5):
foreach (var g in duplicatesWithIndices) {
    Console.WriteLine("Have duplicate " + g.Name + " with indices " +
        string.Join(",", g.Indices.ToArray()));
}

// The output for the above input is:
// > Have duplicate a with indices 0,1,4
// > Have duplicate b with indices 3,5
```

Of course, the provided results must be *used* correctly - and this depends on what must ultimately be done.

Comment: Grouping the indices was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: +1 Nice! - I recommend that you project to a `KeyValuePair<T, int[]>` instead of an anonymous type - that way one could make this an extension method: 

`public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int[]>> GetDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e)
{
 return e.Select((value, index) => new {Index = index, Value = value}).GroupBy(x=>x.Value).Select(xg => new KeyValuePair<T, int[]>(xg.Key, xg.Select(x => x.Index).ToArray())).Where(kv => kv.Value.Length > 1);
}`

(Sorry for the bad formatting)

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = -1;
var currentTargetFiles = targetFileList.Select(x => new
                                                        {
                                                           Value = x,
                                                           Index = i++
                                                        })
                                       .Where(x => x.Value == baselineFilename);
```

Comment: I need the indices of all the items though. And this generated an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @HighCore `Select((x, index) => ..)`

Comment: ok it compiles now but when I run it the value I get is some nonsensical gibberish: {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,int>>}
    base {System.Linq.Enumerable.Iterator<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,int>>}: {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,int>>}

Comment: @user1985189: It's not possible to return a `List<string>` that contains strings *and* list indexes. You can use this to generate the list of anonymous structures, and then create two lists from that.

Comment: @user1985189 post your full code. You're doing ToString() somewhere which is incorrect.

Comment: hmm well baselineFilename is retrieved from a datatable: baselineFilename = (dt.Rows[h]["BASELINE_FILE"].ToString());

Answer (score 1):

Is linq a requirement?

A traditional for loop and a dictionary would do fine:

```
Dictionary<int, string> currentTargetFiles = new Dictionary<int, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < targetFileList.Count; ++i)
    if(targetFileList[i] == baselineFilename)
        currentTargetFiles.Add(i, targetFileList[i]);
```

---

P.S.:

Just realized that you comparing an exact string (`item == baselineFilename`).

If this is the case you don't even need to keep each value for each index (since all values are the same).

```
List<int> currentTargetFilesIndices = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < targetFileList.Count; ++i)
    if(targetFileList[i] == baselineFilename)
        currentTargetFiles.Add(i);
```

Comment: no I don't need linq, it's just that it seemed to be the way everyone was doing it when I googled examples! tbh I don't know anything about linq which is probably pretty apparent